# Split String into to 2 same words

Tags: java, split

I have a String "abcabc" and I want to split it and print like this:

```
abc

abc
```

Code definition for string:

```
String word = "abcabc";
```

Comment: Use a combination of `Pattern` and `Matcher`

Comment: Can you provide more details like - Do you know how many repetitions are there? Will there always be complete repetitions? Can there be other characters?

Answer (score 6):

We can try using `String#replaceAll` for a one line option:

```
String input = "abcabc";
String output = input.replaceAll("^(.*)(?=\\1$).*", "$1\n$1");
System.out.println(output);
```

This prints:

```
abc
abc
```

The idea is to apply a pattern to the entire string which matches and captures some quantity, which is then followed by the same quantity to the end.  Here is the pattern explained as executed against your exact input `abcabc`:

```
(.*)     match 'abc'
(?=\1$)  then lookahead and assert that what follows to the end of the string
         is exactly another 'abc'
.*       consume, but do not match, the remainder of the input (which must be 'abc')
```

Then, we replace with `$1\n$1`, which is the first capture group twice, separated by a newline.

Comment: Will be glad if you can explain the regex `("^(.*)(?=\\1$).*", "$1\n$1")` in more details.

Comment: or 
[String [] array = word.split("(?<=t)");
for(String s : array){
System.out.println(s);

Answer (score 0):

**The string split():**

```
public class Split { 
public static void main(String args[]) 
{ 
String str = "ABC@ABC"; 
String[] arrOfStr = str.split("@", 5); 
for (String a : arrOfStr) 
System.out.println(a); 
} 
}
```

This Also Prints :

```
ABC
ABC
```

Comment: Read the question. update answer with String.split method. Your answer only prints abc twice. He wants to split the string and print.

Comment: @MarkNiles , the input string is not **ABC@ABC** but it **ABCABC**

Answer (score -1):

```
class Stack{
    public static void main(String $[]){
        foo();
    }
    public static void foo(){
        String in="abc abc abc";//spaces are used as seperator.
        String res[]=in.split(" ");//Returns an Array of String 
        for(int i=0;i<res.length;i++)
            System.out.println(res[i]);
    }
}
output:
    abc
    abc
    abc
```